# MVC2 to MV4 conversion error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a project in MVC2, I have converted it to MVC3 then I have converted it to MVC4, I have converted aspx views to Razor Views using [this](http://razorconverter.codeplex.com/) tool,
I also installed MVC3 and MVC4, after converting my application compiled successfully,But when I run the application its showing error

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedRazorViewEngine'
>   to type 'System.Web.Mvc.WebFormViewEngine'.

In Global.asax

```
private static void AddViewPaths()
{
    foreach (var engine in ViewEngines.Engines)
    {              
        ((WebFormViewEngine)engine).PartialViewLocationFormats =
            ((WebFormViewEngine)engine).PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(
            new string[] { "~/Views/Sample/{0}.aspx", "~/Views/Sample/{0}.ascx" }).ToArray();

          ((WebFormViewEngine)engine).ViewLocationFormats =
              ((WebFormViewEngine)engine).ViewLocationFormats.Union(
              new string[] { "~/Views/Sample/{0}.aspx", "~/Views/Sample/{0}.ascx" }).ToArray();
      }
}
```

I tried changing these lines to this,but still same issue,what should I do?

```
 ((WebFormViewEngine)engine).PartialViewLocationFormats =
        ((WebFormViewEngine)engine).PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(
        new string[] { "~/Views/Sample/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Sample/{0}.cshtml" }).ToArray();

  ((WebFormViewEngine)engine).ViewLocationFormats =
        ((WebFormViewEngine)engine).ViewLocationFormats.Union(
        new string[] { "~/Views/Sample/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Sample/{0}.cshtml" }).ToArray();
```

The problem is I am having both Razor and WebForms in ViewEngines.Engines Collection,How can I only get Razor Views

Comment: But you haven't changed anything in your fix: you're still trying to cast `engine` to `WebFormViewEngine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have moved to razor (which was not available in MVC 2), you now have more than just the `WebFormsViewEngine` available in your for loop.  Your code, as written now, it attempting to cast a Razor engine to a WebForms engine, which cannot be done.  If you update the hard casting and remove all other engines, it should work and you can get rid of the for loop - you only have one engine in your collection.

**Application_Start**

```
//clear all but RazorViewEngine
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

Now your updated code would simply be

```
  var engine = ViewEngines.Engines.First();
  ((RazorViewEngine)engine).PartialViewLocationFormats =
    ((RazorViewEngine)engine).PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(
     new string[] { "~/Views/Sample/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Sample/{0}.cshtml" }).ToArray();

  ((RazorViewEngine)engine).ViewLocationFormats =
    ((RazorViewEngine)engine).ViewLocationFormats.Union(
     new string[] { "~/Views/Sample/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Sample/{0}.cshtml" }).ToArray();
```

If you decide not to remove all of the engines, then you are going to have to do an `if/else` inside of your for loop to determine which way to cast the engine.

Comment: @Rup - you're right.  I was just checking my answer in VS and confirmed I had to hard cast to a particular view engine.  If OP removes all engines from the collection and changes his cast, he should be in the clear.  The above edit compiled for me, but since I really don't see what this is doing, I can't test much further.  Thanks for the pointing out of the need for maintaining explicit casting! :)